# How do you set a specific column in each row of a table to a unique value?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to give each user in my database his/her own UUID.  IE, some variation on the following pseudocode:

```
for each row in users {
    set row.uuid = UUID();
}
```

I don't know why but I can't find the answer to this question by Googling or looking at the documentation.  I've found plenty of answers telling me how to set a column to the same value between each row or set the value of a row's column conditionally, but nothing about a basic iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, figured it out.

```
update users set UUID = (select md5(UUID()));
```

Putting md5 around UUID makes it so the UUID is re-generated for each row.